# getting duplicates records when joining in kql

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

We have a requirement to get status of windows service when it is started and stopped do that I have returned one query, but I am facing issue when joining 2 tables to get output.

I have tried using inner and left outer joins but still getting duplicates

```
Event
| where EventLog == "System" and EventID == 7036 and Source == "Service Control Manager"
| parse kind=relaxed EventData with * '<Data Name="param1">' Windows_Service_Name '</Data><Data Name="param2">' Windows_Service_State '</Data>' *
| where Windows_Service_State == "running" and Windows_Service_Name == "Microsoft Monitoring Agent Azure VM Extension Heartbeat Service"
| extend startedtime = TimeGenerated 
| join   (
Event
| where EventLog == "System" and EventID == 7036 and Source == "Service Control Manager"
| parse kind=relaxed EventData with * '<Data Name="param1">' Windows_Service_Name '</Data><Data Name="param2">' Windows_Service_State '</Data>' *
| where Windows_Service_State == "stopped" and Windows_Service_Name == "Microsoft Monitoring Agent Azure VM Extension Heartbeat Service"
| extend stoppedtime = TimeGenerated 
) on Computer 
| extend downtime = startedtime - stoppedtime
| project Computer, Windows_Service_Name,stoppedtime , startedtime  ,downtime
| top 10  by Windows_Service_Name desc
```

we want to get no of times that service started and stopped if the service restarted multiple times in a day we are getting duplicate timings in starttime when joining please have a look on link (https://ibb.co/JzqxjC0)

Comment: attached all started time timings but when joining its only taking 2 timings out of 6  https://imge.to/i/1w1m1

Comment: Dev, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand what is going on, since I don't have access to the data. But. I can see you are using the [default join flavor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#default-join-flavor).

The default is inner unique:

> The inner-join function is like the standard inner-join from the SQL world. An output record is produced whenever a record on the left side has the same join key as the record on the right side.

Which means a new line in the result is created on every match between the left and the right side. Therefore. let's assume you have a computer that was restarted twice, so it has 2 lines of `stopped`, and 2 lines of `running`. That will produce 4 rows in Kusto answer.

Looking at your picture, it makes sense to me because you have lines with negative downtime. I guess that is not possible.

What I would do, is look for an identifier that is unique on every `Computer` run. Then you can join on that, and stay safe not to generate data that you don't want.